# Does Table Partitioning Supports in SQL Server Developer Edition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table Partitioning is supported in Enterprise Edition but its not supported in Standard Edition.
I need to know will it support in the SQL Server Developer Edition?

Comment: Yes: "SQL Server Developer edition lets developers build any kind of application on top of SQL Server. It includes all the functionality of Enterprise edition, but is licensed for use as a development and test system" (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017#Anchor_2))

Comment: [Editions and Components of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017): "It includes all the functionality of Enterprise edition, but is licensed for use as a development and test system, not as a production server"

Comment: Table partitioning is available in all SQL Server editions beginning with SQL Server 2016 SP1. Developer or Enterprise edition only before then.